# Python: Keyboard prompt with capital/noncapital letters

Tags: python, raw-input

In this code:

```
    if raw_input("\n Enter 'y' or 'Y': ")==("y" or "Y"):
       print("\n Success!")
```

It doesn't take the "OR" properly, instead if the in this case noncapital 'y' is entered the condition is fulfilled. If I enter the capital 'Y' I don't get the Success!

What's wrong here?

Comment: Try to understand how Python Interpreter understands the left-hand-side of the statement by typing this in your Python prompt: `print ("y" or "Y")`

Comment: I mean right-hand-side :)

Comment: @Creatronik, did any of the answers help you?

Answer (score 1):

Try this
`if raw_input("\n Enter 'y' or 'Y': ").lower() == "y":`

Answer (score 1):

Try to make a list of values and use the `in` keyword. Something like this will work,

```
if raw_input("\n Enter 'y' or 'Y': ") in ('y', 'Y'):
   print("\n Success!")
```

The `in` keyword tests the string against a tuple of strings and on a correct match it returns `True`.

Since here you have just one character, you can build a string `"yY"`. Something like this will work,

```
if raw_input("\n Enter 'y' or 'Y': ") in "yY":
   print("\n Success!")
```

Here each character of the string acts like one element of the tuple above.

---

**ERROR in your code:**
You used `("y" or "Y")`. This does not work in Python. This will only return `"y"` as both `"y"` and `"Y"` are treated as `True` values. However, if you type `(0 or "Y")`, you will get `"Y"` as `0` is treated as a `False` value.

Answer (score 0):

The right-hand-side of your if-statement is wrong and I think you need to understand a little better how the `or` operator behaves between strings.

Keep in mind that the return value of `or` is the value that has been evaluated last, and that Python evaluates empty string as boolean `False` and non-empty strings as boolean `True`.

In your case, the interpreter reads `("y" or "Y")`, it then evaluates the boolean value of "y" which is `True`, as it is a non-empty string. Therefore, the boolean value of the `or` statement it `True` and the return value of the statement becomes "y", the last evaluated value.

This is how I would write this code. I would keep the return value of `raw_input` in `_input`, which will make it easier for me and others to read and understand the if-statement:

```
_input = raw_input("\n Enter 'y' or 'Y': ")

if input in ["y", "Y"]:
    print("\n Success!")
```

Answer (score 0):

> What's wrong here?

In many programming languages, `OR` is a boolean operator. You apply it to values that are TRUE or FALSE. The operation evaluates to TRUE if at least one operand is TRUE:

```
TRUE OR TRUE == TRUE
TRUE OR FALSE == TRUE
FALSE OR TRUE == TRUE
FALSE OR FALSE == FALSE
```

[In Python, you can apply `or` on non-boolean operands](https://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=boolean#boolean-operations-and-or-not):

```
x or y
```

returns `x` if `x` casted to `boolean` is `True`; else it returns `y`. For boolean operands, this leads to the same results as above, but for non-boolean operands this has interesting effects:

- `[] or {}` is `{}` (because empty lists are `False` when casted to
  `boolean`)
- `[1] or {}` is `[1]` (because non-empty lists are `True` when casted to `boolean`)
- `[1] or 1/0` is also `[1]` (the right operand doesn't even get evaluated when the left one is `True`, so we don't hit the `ZeroDivisionError`. This is known as [(left-to-right) short-circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).)

Thus, other than in natural language, the **Python `or` cannot be interpreted as separating alternative values.** (Only alternative conditions / boolean expressions.)

There are several possibilities on how to make your code behave as expected:

The naive approach:

```
answer = raw_input("\n Enter 'y' or 'Y': ")
if answer == "y" or answer == "Y":
   print("\n Success!")
```

Normalizing the input:

```
if raw_input("\n Enter 'y' or 'Y': ").lower() == 'y':
   print("\n Success!")
```

Comparing to set of alternative values with membership operator `in`:

```
if raw_input("\n Enter 'y' or 'Y': ") in {'y', 'Y'}:
   print("\n Success!")
```